# How can I select the first sequence of 4 numbers in a string with regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following string:

```
aasd2016/20182000 2019asd
```

I want a regex pattern that matches the **first** sequence of 4 digits. In this case I want the regex to return:

`2016`

I have tried the following:

```
\d{4}(.*?)
```

I thought the `(.*?)` meant non greedy matching (matching a few as possible) but it matches every sequence of 4 numbers.

**Edit**

I am using this with the python library pandas to filter out weirdly formatted "buildYear" column in a dataframe:

```
pattern = r"\d{4}(.*?)"
filter = all_objects["buildYear"].str.contains(pattern)
all_objects = all_objects[filter]
```

Comment: `\d{4}` will do it, then just search for the first match. `.*?` will do nothing, it'll just match zero characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 \d{4}
```

without `g` flag

```js
let str = `aasd2016/20182000 2019asd`

let op = str.match(/\d{4}/)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're working with a `DataFrame`, you could use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'buildYear': [
        'aasd2016/20182000 2019asd', 'axc2000 33 2014', 'spam33_20/2018 2019'
    ]})

df['result'] = df['buildYear'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})')
```

```py
    buildYear                   result
0   aasd2016/20182000 2019asd   2016
1   axc2000 33 2014             2000
2   spam33_20/2018 2019         2018
```

---

In pure Python, an equivalent to @Code Maniac's answer would be to use `re.search`

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = 'aasd2016/20182000 2019asd'
>>> re.search(r'(\d{4})', s).group(1)
'2016'
```